# String clustering in Python

Tags: python, string, scipy, cluster-analysis

I have a list of strings and I want to classify it by using clustering in Python.

```py
list = ['String1', 'String2', 'String3',...]
```

I want to use Levenshtein distance, so I used jellyfish library. Given two strings, I know that their distance can be found this way:

```py
jellyfish.levenshtein_distance('string1', 'string2')
```

My problem is that I don't know how to use `scipy.cluster.hierarchy` to get a list in Python of each cluster. I have also tried using linkage function:

```py
linkage(y[, method, metric])
```

But I am not able to get the final list with clusters.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638130/tutorial-for-scipy-cluster-hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

After using [`linkage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html) for implementing hierarchical clustering on the distance you have, you should use `cluster.hierarchy.cut_tree` to cut the tree.
If you want two clusters:

```
cluster.hierarchy.cut_tree(linkage_output,2).ravel() #.ravel makes it 1D array.
```